# SQL check if more than one field in range is >0

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL-Server, I have 4 fields in a table and I want check whether more than one is >0 and if so set the value of a new field to 1. For example,

```
RowID Football Cricket Tennis Athletics
1     0        2       0      1
2     1        0       0      0
```

Row one would evaluate to 1, row two wouldn't.

How do I construct a case statement to evaluate the multiple fields?

Thanks

Comment: what you tried so far

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of:
"case when xx then 1 else 0 end NewField". I'm not sure how to evaluate only in 2 or more fields are >0 though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following,

```
Select RowId, Case when NewField > 1 then 1 else 0 end as 'Status' from 
(
    Select *,
        case when Football > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when Cricket > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when Tennis > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when Athletics > 0 then 1 else 0 end as 'NewField'
    from TableName
)
```

Comment: Good answer: this approach is easily modified if you want to test for e.g. at least 2 fields being >0, or if you have more than 4 fields you need to check.  Just using `AND` and `OR` (which I was going to answer with) rapidly becomes unworkable in these cases as the number of combinations to test grows very rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Purely in the concept of what's possible, so I'm not saying it's better or worse, you can also unpivot your results first to normalize the data.

For example, this would display the sports and their count underneath each other:

```
select RowID, Sport, SportCount
from YourTableName
unpivot
( SportCount for Sport in (Football, Cricket, Tennis, Athletics )) up
```

From there it's relatively simple to get the number of sports per id:

```
select rowid, SUM(case when SportCount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) NumberOfSports from(
select RowID,  SportCount
from YourTableName
unpivot
( SportCount for Sport in (Football, Cricket, Tennis, Athletics )) up
) q group by rowid
```

Or to use it in the update query for number of sports > 2 (other approaches possible of course)

```
update YourTableName set SomeField = 1 where RowID in
(
select rowid from(
select RowID,  SportCount
from YourTableName
unpivot
( SportCount for Sport in (Football, Cricket, Tennis, Athletics )) up
) q group by rowid
having SUM(case when SportCount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 1)
```

The advantage of going through the trouble of unpivoting, is that the logic of the criterium is in one place. If in the future you want to see all rows with more than one sport with a count for more than 2, there's only one place where it is updated. Performance wise I'd probably stick to using a `case footb + case cricket + ..` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tests
    ( RowID ,
      Football ,
      Cricket ,
      Tennis ,
      Athletics
    )VALUES  ( 1 , -- RowID - int
      0 , -- Football - int
      2 , -- Cricket - int
      0 , -- Tennis - int
      1  -- Athletics - int
    ),
    ( 1 , -- RowID - int
      0 , -- Football - int
      2 , -- Cricket - int
      0 , -- Tennis - int
      1  -- Athletics - int
    )
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(select *from dbo.tests
unpivot (value for name in (Football,Cricket,Tennis,Athletics)) up
pivot (max(value) for RowID in ([1],[2])) p) AS t WHERE [1]>0
```

Thanks